# Normal Distribution of Error Terms

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, residuals

I have a question.  Would the error terms follow a normal distribution based on the attached plot graphs.  The data on the y-axis follows steps so they are in exact increments (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).  Those values being in steps are throwing me off.

[image: Normal Distribution]

Comment: Excel has drawn the probability plot with such a depressed aspect ratio that it's almost impossible to identify deviations from linearity.  Regardless of the wisdom or meaningfulness of characterizing a random variable with only six values as "normal," you should at least stretch that plot vertically by a factor of about 4:1 so you can see what it has to show.